# New Water Heater problems

Tags: water, heater

Hi all and thanks in advance for any help I receive on this.

Just installed a new A.O. Smith Signature 100 Electric 50 gal. Made sure to fill tank completely before flipping breaker on. Waited 2 hrs and tried the hot water it lasted around 10 mins then the water temp started to drop at about 20 mins its down to 72 degrees.

I have checked both elements both were at 12 on the resistance. I went ahead and replaced the lower, for no good reseaon other than "well, maybe". I checked both thermostats and they seem to be functioning correctly.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If pushing 5 gallons per minute, then 50 gallons last 10 minutes.  2 hours for 50 cold gallons might be wishful thinking.

Answer (score 2):

That is normal performance for a 50 gal heater, especially if the set point was at the lower end of the adjustment (say 120 deg.), as would be required (if there are no additional fancy tempering valves, etc.) in many jurisdictions. The solution would be to jack the setpoint up and install all those fancy expensive tempering valves.